# I am getting an Aggregate Function/Group by Error from a column name in a join function

Tags: sql

Receiving the error "column 'entityotherarrangements.custfrmdataid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause". Where I am getting stuck is this column is part of a join statement

Here is what I have

```
Declare @FromDate nvarchar(50), @ToDate nvarchar(50);
Set @FromDate = '20180905'
SET @ToDate = '20180917'
SELECT
arrangements.[Description] AS 'invitename',
count(entityotherarrangements.[Type]) as 'passcount',
(Select ISNULL(FullName,'') FROM Entity Where EntityId=
   (SELECT top 1 entityidvalue
      From CustomFormFields
      WHERE CustomFormFields.FieldId = 504
      AND CustomFormFields.CustFrmDataId = Entityotherarrangements.CustFrmDataId 
    )
) AS 'filmcoordinator'
FROM entityotherarrangements
LEFT JOIN customformdata 
  ON entityotherarrangements.CustFrmDataId = customformdata.CustFrmDataId
LEFT join arrangements 
  ON Entityotherarrangements.ArrangementNumber = arrangements.Number_SQL
WHERE CustomFormData.CustFrmDefinitionId = 17 
  AND arrangements.Type_Number = 71 
  AND CONVERT(varchar,arrangements.Date_First_Event,112)
  BETWEEN @fromDate and @ToDate
Group by arrangements.description
```

**Expected Output**

```
invitename  passcount   filmcoordinator                                                
Green       3           John Doe   
Blue        5           John Doe  
Purple      8           Helen Buck  
Black       4           Helen Buck
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use aggregate functions (like count), any other field that is not aggregated must be in the group by.  So you have 3 choices:

1. Put your subquery in the group by as well (though I don't know if this would work, as I wouldn't write the query this way, but it might).
2. Do an aggregate expression around your subquery.
3. Don't use subqueries in the select clause.  Instead put all the tables, subqueries, etc. in the FROM.  This will be the cleanest and save you other problems in the future.